# Bitrise and bitbucket server

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitrise

Does `bitrise` support integration with bitbucket server?

If so can you please point to instructions on how to setup the hook? I tried to use [this hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/post-service-webhook-for-bitbucket-server-776640367.html) but got no luck.

Also can I connect user account in `bitrise` to bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

> Does bitrise support integration with bitbucket server?

Depends on whether the webhook format of bitbucket server is the same as bitbucket.org's.

How webhook handling works in Bitrise.io: [bitrise.io](https://www.bitrise.io) supports only it's own Build Trigger API. This API is used by the web interface when you start a build manually, as well as you can call it via curl or from any other tool ([related DevCenter guide](http://devcenter.bitrise.io/docs/build-trigger-api)).

Service specific webhook formats are handled in the "webhook transformer" server. This server has a single purpose, it transforms service specific webhook calls (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket, Slack, VSTS, Gogs, … webhook formats) to Bitrise.io Build Trigger API calls, performs the call and then returns the response (build started / failed to start the build).

The code of the server is [open source](https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-webhooks), you can run it on your own servers, change anything in the code and send a Pull Request with your changes (if you run it on your own servers this is not mandatory). The latest release version is available & hosted free of charge at [hooks.bitrise.io](http://hooks.bitrise.io).

> Also can I connect user account in bitrise to bitbucket?

bitbucket.org accounts can be connected, bitbucket server accounts can't - but you can do the setup manually, without connecting a bitbucket server account.

In any case, if you have a feature request (e.g. you don't have time to implement the webhook transformation) feel free to create a feature request on [UserVoice](https://bitrise.uservoice.com) or on GitHub (preferably in the related GitHub repo, or if it can be implemented as open source then in the [bitrise-io/bitrise-contrib](https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-contrib) repo).

Answer (score 0):

Bitrise recently rolled out an update (Oct. 6, 2016) that fully connects to the Bitbucket API for triggering builds with code pushes, pull requests, etc. New apps that use Github or Bitbucket are already setup with a webhook. Instructions for setting up the webhook for existing apps are as follows:

> To get the webhook URL from Bitrise, select your app on the Bitrise Dashboard and select the Code tab, where you can find your Build trigger URL.
>
> If your source code provider is Bitbucket visit the Bitbucket website, select your repository, then go to the repository settings. Under Integrations, select Webhooks, then click the Add webhook button. Paste your webhook URL in the field, add a title and make sure the "Repository push" is set as a trigger. Currently Bitrise only supports the default Push trigger. When done select Save.

Full instructions can be found [here](http://devcenter.bitrise.io/docs/setup-webhook#section-bitbucket).